# content layout is spole when we put html in ckediotor

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

when  i  put HTML code  in ck editor text area then the style is changed i have give HTML content so  when  i save that ck-editor data then the layout of HTML is totally different and also ck editor add extra space in that  HTML tag so any suggestive for that .

i have application  in that i am creating PDF .so to edit pdf data i first show in ck editor  so when this data is saved then ck-editor add extra space between HTML tag like extra '
'
tag and also extra nbsp; tag or html enity so is there any way we can ignore this one and save as original so

Thanks

Comment: what in the world does "spole" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

umm, if I understand you right, then It could be if you have not defined a

```
<DOCTYPE ....>
```

which means that different browsers and editors will render it differently.  Hope this helps :)